# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lorg/springframework/beans/factory/access/BeanFactoryReference;

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, gradle

I am trying to deploy my application on tomcat 9 but during deployment I am facing following exception

> org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component
> [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/party-request-v2]]
> at
> org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:441)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:742)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:718)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:703)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:986)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:492)
> at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1651)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:287)
> at
> com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
> at
> com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.check(ManagerServlet.java:1571)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.upload(HTMLManagerServlet.java:294)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.doPost(HTMLManagerServlet.java:212)
> at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)     at
> javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)  at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.filters.CsrfPreventionFilter.doFilter(CsrfPreventionFilter.java:136)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
> at
> org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:611)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.valves.RequestFilterValve.process(RequestFilterValve.java:348)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve.invoke(RemoteAddrValve.java:52)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:137)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:651)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
> at
> org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:414)
> at
> org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
> at
> org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:754)
> at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1376)
> at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
> at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
> at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
> at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by:
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
> **Lorg/springframework/beans/factory/access/BeanFactoryReference;**   at
> java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)     at
> java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2583)     at
> java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1916)    at
> org.apache.catalina.util.Introspection.getDeclaredFields(Introspection.java:110)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.populateAnnotationsCache(DefaultInstanceManager.java:314)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:173)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:143)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.createListener(ApplicationContext.java:1179)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.addListener(ApplicationContext.java:1092)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContextFacade.addListener(ApplicationContextFacade.java:648)
> at
> org.temp.atom.core.configuration.AbstractAtomWebApplicationInitializer.createAppContextLoaderListener(AbstractAtomWebApplicationInitializer.java:58)
> at
> org.temp.atom.service.configuration.AtomServiceApplicationInitializer.onStartup(AtomServiceApplicationInitializer.java:78)
> at
> org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:169)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5055)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
> ... 45 more Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
> **org.springframework.beans.factory.access.BeanFactoryReference   at**
> org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1292)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1121)
> ... 60 more

dependencies.gradle is as follows

```
compile (
        'org.eclipse.persistence:javax.persistence:2.0.0.v200911041116',
        'javax.activation:activation:1.1-20060419',
        'commons-lang:commons-lang:2.2',
        'javax.xml:jsr173:1.0',
        'commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:3.1',
        'javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.5',
        'regexp:regexp:1.3',
        'org.aspectj:aspectjrt:1.8.4',
        'org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:1.8.4',
        'org.springframework:spring-aspects:4.0.5.RELEASE',
        'org.springframework:spring-jdbc:4.0.5.RELEASE',
        'org.springframework:spring-jms:4.0.5.RELEASE',
        'org.springframework:spring-orm:4.0.5.RELEASE',
        'org.springframework:spring-oxm:4.0.5.RELEASE',
        'org.springframework:spring-instrument-tomcat:4.0.5.RELEASE',
        'com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:2.1.13',
        'com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-xjc:2.1.13'
    )
    testCompile (
        'junit:junit:4.10',
        'c3p0:c3p0:0.9.1.2',
        'org.springframework:spring-test:4.0.5.RELEASE',
    )
```

**Note : Same application is running successfully on weblogic 12.**

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the dependencies in the `gradle` file or add it in your `compile`:

```
dependencies {  
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-beans', version: '4.0.5.RELEASE'    
}
```

And now you need to do gradle refrech.

Comment: How it is working on weblogic 12 without "spring-beans" dependency

Comment: i did not work with weblogic but maybe it contains this dependency or it contains another project that use this dependency

Comment: Neither it contain dependency nor another project uses this dependency

Comment: then i think it is only  problem of gradle refrech

Comment: org.springframework:spring-beans:4.1.5.RELEASE -> 5.0.0.RELEASE (*)

Comment: i seleted this version because i sow that you are using it in another spring dependencies , so i think the answer is correct

Comment: No it is called transitive dependency resolution.

Comment: and when you added this version in tomcat it works ??